# How to get position of hyperlink tag while parsing DOCX document.xml with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, hyperlink, xml-parsing, docx

My aim is to parse DOCX file with PHP for all hyperlinks in format:

`<start of hyperlink(number of the first element of hyperlink in text)>, 
<end of hyperlink(number of the last element of hyperlink in text)>, 
<hyperlink text>`

For example:

> *input*: "Hello, absolutely **terrible**`{adjective: distressing}(you cannot see this in .docx file)` world!"
>
> *output*: {19, 26, "adjective: distressing"}

For now I've done code to parse all the hyperlinks as plain text, but I cannot get numbers of its position in text. Here is my code:

```
define("dir", "Dictations");
define("test_file", "Dictation_Text.docx");

/**
 * @param $filename
 * @return string
 */
function getHyperLinks($filename) {
    $explode_result = explode('.', $filename);
    $extension = end($explode_result);
    if ($extension == "docx") {
        $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
    }
else {
    return "DOCX files only supported";
}
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filename) === true) {
    if (($zip_index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($zip_index);
        $parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $data, $values, $indexes);
        xml_parser_free($parser);
        $result = Array();
        foreach ($indexes["W:HYPERLINK"] as $ind) {
            if ($values[$ind]["type"] == "open") {
                $result[] = $values[$ind]["attributes"]["W:ANCHOR"];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    else {
        return "File " . $filename . " couldn't be found in " . document;
    }
}
    else {
        return "Couldn't open archive " . $filename;
    }
}

#TODO: getting filename from front by $_GET
$document = dir . "/" . test_file;
$result = getHyperLinks($document);
if (is_array($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        echo $res . "\n";
    }
}
else {
    echo $result;
}
```

So I couldn't find any XML attribute of starting position of hyperlink, please tell me how to get it or some way to get it from XMLObject or maybe show me another more convenient way to parse DOCX file to get all the info I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks generally fine, but you're looking in the wrong file.

.docx link elements aren't stored in document.xml.  Weird, right?

**word/_rels/document.xml.rels** has all that data (or **header1.xml.rels**, etc.).

If you want to see the format, re-name your .docx to a .zip.  Then you can extract it and view all the .xml files inside.  Each link gets a line of XML, so if all you need are the links, you may not need to parse from document.xml at all.

If you do need context, you'll go by the association of the "Id" variable on each Relationship.

Comment: Thanks, helped alot)